# How to run a script from file in another project using include in GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run a shell script from my template file located in another project via my include.

How should this be configured to work? Below scripts are simplified versions of my code.

#### Project A

`template.yml`

```
deploy:
  before_script:
    - chmod +x ./.run.sh
    - source ./.run.sh
```

#### Project B

`gitlab-ci.yml`

```
include:
 - project: 'project-a'
    ref: master
    file: '/template.yml'

stages:
  - deploy
```

Clearly, the commands are actually being run from *ProjectB* and not *ProjectA* where the template resides. This can further be confirmed by adding `ls -a` in the template file.

So how should we be calling `run.sh`? Both projects are on the same GitLab instance under different groups.

Comment: So you want to execute shell script by `Project B` pipeline, but in scope of `Project A`? For example `ls -a` should print files from `Project A` in the pipeline that runs in `Project B`? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @rkm that is correct. In my example, *Project A* contains `run.sh`. But since I'm including `template.yml` in *Project B*, it can't see `run.sh`. I'm trying to include *Project A* and its dependencies.

Comment: the question is duplicated here:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/241808

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have access project A and B, you can use [multi-project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html). You [trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger) a pipeline in project A from project B.

In project A, you clone project B and run your script.

### Project B

```yaml
job 1:
  variables:
    PROJECT_PATH: "$CI_PROJECT_PATH"
    RELEASE_BRANCH: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
  trigger:
    project: project-a
    strategy: depend
```

### Project A

```yml
job 2:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline" && $PROJECT_PATH && $RELEASE_BRANCH'
  script:
    - git clone -b "${RELEASE_BRANCH}" --depth 50 https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${PROJECT_PATH}.git $(basename ${PROJECT_PATH})
    - cd $(basename ${PROJECT_PATH})
    - chmod +x ../.run.sh
    - source ../.run.sh
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly how I’ve accomplished this. It works really well and I wasn’t aware of this feature. Now I have a CI repository doing all my fancy stuff for a bunch of other projects (builds, deploys, etc.) this is fantastic. If anyone is wondering, you can also set a trigger branch. I found this to be extremely useful for different versions or languages (e.g. I have a `build` project that works for different languages, a `python` branch for building `python` and a `nodejs` branch to build `nodejs`).

Comment: How do the variables from Project B become accessible in Project A? I do not understand how that works in this answer.

Comment: I actually want the stuff to run from project B to show up on project A's CI logs. If not the developer of project A can ignore the templates that were setup on project B.

Comment: Doesn't multi-project pipelines mean running external scripts on the external pipeline?  I think the user is asking how to run external scripts *on the current pipeline.*

Comment: @john-ktejik, [When you use the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` to trigger pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html#create-multi-project-pipelines-by-using-the-api) (or use [trigger key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger)), GitLab recognizes the source of the job token. The pipelines become related, so you can visualize their relationships on pipeline graphs.

Answer (score 13):

We've also run into this problem, and kinda wish Gitlab allowed `include`s to "import" non-yaml files. Nevertheless the simplest workaround we've found is to **build a small docker image in repo A, which contains the script you want to run**, and then repo B's job uses that docker image as the `image`, so the file `run.sh` is available :)

Minimal Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM bash:latest
COPY run.sh /usr/local/bin/
CMD run.sh
```

(Note: make sure you `chmod +x run.sh` before building your image, or add a `RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run.sh` step)

Then, you'd just add this to your Project B's `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/...  # Wherever you pushed your docker image to
  script: run.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

it's also possible to request a script by curl instead of copying a whole repository:

```
- curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$PRIVATE_TOKEN" --create-dirs "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_DEPLOY_PROJECT_ID/repository/archive?path=pathToFolderWithScripts" -o $TEMP_DIR/archive.tar.gz
- tar zxvf $TEMP_DIR/archive.tar.gz -C $TEMP_DIR --strip-components 3
- bash $TEMP_DIR/run.sh
```

- to make a curl request
- to archive a folder with scripts
- to unzip scripts in a temporary folder
- to execute sh

Answer (score -1):

As hinted by the answer above, [multi project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html) is the right approach for it.

Here's how it worked for me:

**GroupX/ProjectA** - contains reusable code

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - deploy

reusable_deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"'   # run only if triggered by a pipeline
  script:
    - bash ./src/run.sh $UPSTREAM_CUSTOM_VARIABLE
```

**GroupY/ProjectB** - job that will reuse a code

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - deploy

deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    UPSTREAM_CUSTOM_VARIABLE: CUSTOM_VARIABLE   # pass this variable to downstream job
  trigger: groupx/projecta
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Doesn't this trigger scripts in the *other* pipeline?  This does technically answer the question as asked, but I think the user is asking how to run external scripts on the *current* pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

ref This :: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository

`GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path/raw`

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb?ref=master"
```

It will display the file.

To download this file just add `>> <filename>`
as below

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb?ref=master" >> file.extension
```